# Selenium clicking on a different element on two different machine

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have this below code to locate an element on a page.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Add']")).click();

The above code works perfectly on

Machine 1: Windows 7 64 bit, Firefox Browser, selenium-java-2.45.0

but click's on another web element when run on

Machine 2: Windows 7 64 bit Firefox Browser, selenium-2.53.0

Note: There is only one Add Element on the page

Comment: post your HTML code of ADD element.

Comment: Did U check it in different browsers ?? Did U checked in known issues database? Did U use docker in your setups??

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement addElement = wait.until(
  ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Add']")));
addElement.click();
```

Comment: I can't give you a better answer without knowing more about your HTML and setup.

Comment: If you view the loaded page source (HTML) and search for 
 "script" tags, do they reference the keywords "jquery","angular" or "prototpye"?  If so your problem may be Javascript.  If the wait for clickable answer doesn't help then the next suggestion depends on your answer to the above question.